# Prove that $T_a$ is a bounded linear operator on $(\ell^\infty,||\cdot||_\infty)$, and find the operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing, normed-spaces

I am trying to prove that $T_a$ is a bounded linear operator on $(\ell^\infty,||\cdot||_\infty)$, and that $||T_a||_{op}=||a||_\infty$ with $a = (a_n)_{n\geq 1}\in\ell^\infty$ and $T_a:\ell^\infty\to\ell^\infty$, where $T_ax\mapsto(a_nx_n)_{n\geq 1}\,,\forall x\in\ell^\infty$. This is my working so far:

Let $x\in\ell^\infty$. If $x=0\,\implies||T_a0||=\sup_{n\geq 1}|0|=0=||T_a||_{op}||0||$ and hence $T_a$ is bounded.

if $x\neq 0$ then $||x||>0$. So for $x'=\frac{x}{||x||}\implies ||x'||=1$ and hence: $$||T_ax'||\leq||T_a||_{op}\space\text{as}\space||T_a||_{op}=\sup\{||T_ax||:x\in\ell^\infty,||x||\leq1\}$$

Therefore, we have: $$||T_ax'||=\lVert T\left(\frac{x}{||x||}\right)\rVert=\frac{1}{||x||}||T_ax||\leq||T_a||_{op}\implies||T_ax||\leq||T_a||_{op}||x||$$

Hence, $T_a$ is bounded.

To show the value of $||T_a||_{op}$ we can see that if we choose $x\,,\text{ s.t }||x||=1$ we can see that we already have a lower bound for $||T_a||_{op}$:

$$||T_ax||=\sup_{n\geq 1}|a_nx_n|\leq\sup_{n\geq 1}|a_n|\sup_{n\geq 1}|x_n|=\sup_{n\geq 1}|a_n|=||a||\leq||T_a||_{op}$$

I do not know how to show this the other way.

Is what I have done so far correct and can someone tell me how to show the inequality in the other direction?

Comment: The fact that $T_a$ is bounded does not come from the fact that $||T_ax||\leq||T_a||_{op}||x||$, since that statement is always true, whether $||T_a||_{op} = +\infty$ or not. Also, what you showed at the end is actually that $||a|| \geq ||T_a||_{op}$, and not the other way around, but at least that does mean that $T_a$ is bounded (but only now, not before bounding $||T_a||_{op}$ from above).

Comment: As for the other way, it comes down to searching for an example for which you have $||T_ax|| = ||a||$ (though in some cases the norm is not always attained, in which case you can instead try looking for a sequence such that the image sequence's norms converge to the desired number).

Comment: @BrunoB I see how what I have done initially doesn't mean that $T_a$ is bounded, but I am unsure as to how the inequality is the wrong way around, would you be able to tell me?

Comment: Essentially: $||T_a||_{op} = \inf \{C \mid \forall x,\, ||T_ax|| \leq C ||x||\}$ (it's one of the equivalent ways to define the operator norm). Thus, if you find a number, here it's $||a||$, which is one of those $C$s, then what you have is that $||T_a||_{op} \leq C$.